# How to handle browser prompts in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, prompt

The scenario is, when I click a button browser would show an alert which accepts user input field with OK and cancel buttons. Now please tell me how to handle this type of alert. As we know CasperJS doesn't displays the alert windows.
[image: This is the prompt window]

This is the casperJS code

```
casper.then(function () {
        this.click('#new-asset > a:nth-child(1)');
        casper.setFilter("page.prompt", function(msg, currentValue) {
            if (msg === "Choose a filename for your asset") {
                return "Firsr.txt";
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily solve this by using a Filter in CasperJS. The appropriate one is [`page.prompt`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-prompt):

```
// put somewhere before the prompt appears
casper.setFilter("page.prompt", function(msg, currentValue) {
    if (msg === "What's your name?") {
        return "Chuck";
    }
});
```

Such a dialog is called a prompt (`window.prompt()`) which is distinct from an `window.alert()` or `window.confirm()`.

Comment: I have added the screen shot of that prompt window, now how do you click on 'Ok' and 'cancel' and also provided the sample code..

Comment: B, When i click on new asset, nothing is going on

Comment: Well, you should define the filter before you click anything that opens a prompt.

Comment: yeah...it worked but, it is not completing the script. Even though i haven't given any wait(); but still it is getting stuck over there..

Comment: it is working.....and tell me one more thing, what if i want to click on cancel button then??

Comment: I don't know. Maybe return `null`/`false`. If that doesn't work, then one would need to change the implementation of `window.prompt()` on-the-fly. Tell me what you find.

Comment: B  when i debug the scripts, it is showing 'Console: OOB send arrived: ['console.err']
Console: OOB send arrived: ['console.err']'

Comment: I have no idea what "OOB send arrived" is supposed to be. It's probably a custom error message of the page.

Comment: okay, then how to end that script? even thought i have written 'casper.run(function () {
        test.done();
    });' but still it is not terminating

Comment: Did it terminate before you implemented this? Are you on windows? Did you install CasperJS through npm?

Comment: ya, i am windows but running Ubuntu through VM. For all the scripts it is terminating but when you suggest to add the solution, from then it is performing the specified operation but after that, it hung over there only. And i haven't installed it through npm